# Reconciling browser-side and server-side authentication

Tags: session, cookies, authorization, parse-platform

apologies if this has been asked but I'm trying to figure out this kind of stuff for the first time -

I'm developing an app where I want to divide the authenticated content from the web-facing side, completely; therefore I am not using a simple backbone.js-style "keep all views in one file" (unless I'm wrong about this, please illuminate!) but actually divided server files (using PHP).

Current flow: the user logs in client-side (using the [Parse.com Todo app](https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript) as an example) and, if successful, I store cookie (via POST/AJAX) with user email and the returned sessionToken on client side. I then thought that when user next visits site, the server can read cookie and shuffle the user to the private/locked portion of site, which, again, is a different set of PHP files.

Here I get lost -- how do I then tell Parse.com that the user is logged in, if I don't have her username/password (only email), and start grabbing data from the classes? Is there a way to do this that I'm not recognizing? I guess I can load different .JS files, read if a session exists, and JS-redirect to a different url, but that seems to me to be a weird way of going about it.

Is there a general philosophy/methodology to my questions that I should read up on, along concrete advice dealing with Parse.com questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Parse User session management functions should be good for you.

Check out https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webapp-users

There is an example at the bottom of their announcement blog post here: http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/new-cloud-modules-for-images-and-users/

It gives you user session management with minimal effort.